# PHPMailer add array values to mail

Tags: php, arrays, email, phpmailer

I have this PHPMailer that sends out an email to me if a script has run.

I want to add some array values to the mailcontent but it seems to fail.
When I did my mailing through the `mail()` function and that worked.

Here is what I have:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();                                                    
$mail->Host = 'www.domain.com';                 
$mail->Port = 465;                                              
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                         
$mail->Username = "usernamen.nl";    
$mail->Password = "password";                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                      

$mail->From = 'from@domain.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Import Users';
$mail->AddAddress('to@domain.com', 'CronJob results'); 

$mail->IsHTML(true);                                                

$mail->Subject = 'CronJob results';
$mail->Body    = 'Updated users'.implode($update, "<br />").'

                Added users'.implode($add, "<br />").'

                Deleted users'.implode($delete, "<br />").'
                                                ';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}
```

`$update`, `$add` and `$delete` are the array that are filled with their corresponding data.

M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are making a small mistake in implode. you should use implode like this

```
implode( "<br />",$add);
```

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time. Thank you!

Comment: waah. @syedmohamed. Aaj.. sab jagah aapka he answer hain. Umda. Behatrin. Zindabad.